# Rules for determining the position of alles in “was / wer + alles” in a sentence to mean “who all, what all”

Tags: sentence-structure

There have been a few posts ([here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22489/what-does-alles-mean-here) and [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/44289/was-denn-noch-alles/44292#44292)) to explain that the meaning of *alles* along with *was* or *wer* is to emphasize a large group of people or things - all the things, who all etc.

**What are the rules determining the position of alles?**

I have tried to form some rules around how to use *alles* based on the following examples:

**W- Questions**

> 1. **Wer** kommt denn **alles**?
> 2. **Was** macht Sylvie **alles**?
> 3. **Was** denn noch **alles**?
> 4. **Was** hast du dort **alles** gekauft?

Possible rules:
*alles* goes at the end of the question – Example (1), (2) and (3), or before the participle – Example (4)

**Sentences**

> 5. Der Ausstellungsbereich zeigt, **was** und **wen** es **alles** braucht(e), damit man überhaupt telefonieren kann.
> 6. Hasslnüsse, Walnüsse, Mandeln, Orangen, Honig, Marzipan und **was** sonst noch **alles** zum beliebten Lebkuchen gehört.
> 7. Eigentlich gar nicht so langweilig hier, denn **wen** man hier **alles** trifft!

Possible rules:

1. „*was sonst noch alles*” is a set phrase for “whatever else” – Example (6)
2. *alles* goes before the conjugated verb – Example (5) and (7)

Comment: All examples are correct... As I don‘t know what you already tried there is no way to answer this... there is no real question here... please show us examples of what you tried to say and why you think they are wrong.... „alles“ is just a replacement for a part of the sentence... it can stand nearly everywhere in the sentence as it can replace the subject or any object of the sentence...

Comment: @TorstenLink Many thanks for the feedback on my original post.  I have expanded the examples that I have found and shown the corresponding rules that I think could be used.  I hope this helps in answering.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Nobody will be able to answer if you don't ask any question.

Comment: I find the question understandable: What are the rules determining the position of *alles*? For instance, *Wer kommt alles denn?* sounds pretty bad, while *denn wen man alles hier trifft!* seems fine.

Comment: @DavidVogt Many thanks, your summary is exactly what I wanted to know.  I have updated my post as such.  Thanks again.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Thanks for the comment!  I have explicitly added the question that I need help with.  Many thanks!

Comment: Just a few hints, not an answer: In a more general way, you might want to ask the position of elements like _sonst noch (so)_, _überhaupt_, _noch_, _außerdem_, _eigentlich_,  …, referring to interrogatives used in questions or relative clauses (even _Wo in Deutschland_ spricht _man das ‘r’_ überall _gerollt aus?_ or: Wo _sind die Leute_ alle _hin_? have an analogue structure).  As you see in the set of interchangeable elements, _alles_ works like a modal particle (Abtönungspartikel) and has a quantifying aspect.  ...

Comment: ... In your examples it takes the position before the right sentence bracket, repectively at the end, if there is no verbal bracket. In those cases, it is the at same place that an adverb like _heute_ would take. Differently fom _heute_ ,you can also place it directly after the “w-word”: _ich weiß nicht mehr, wer alles kommt / … wen alles ich da getroffen hatte_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite broad, for now I will try to answer it for W-sentences.

1. "Alles" can go behind the question word (or question word group), if it is emphasized:

> "[Was] alles hast du gekauft?

2. If not put behind the question word, "alles" usually has the sentence position before preposition groups and past participles:

> Was hast du heute denn noch alles [im Supermarkt] [gekauft]?

Rule 2 is only a rule of thumb. Unfortunately, there are a lot of possible positions that are difficult to generalize. For example, adverbs may be moved behind "alles" (here "noch").

> Was hast du heute denn alles [noch] [im Supermarkt] [gekauft]?

The problem is, not all of these positionings are grammatically sound. To be sure the sentence is correct, you should stick to rule 2.

Also note that the preposition group can be moved forward.

> Was hast du heute [im Supermarkt] denn noch alles [gekauft]?